# Should I turn off my Magic Mouse when carrying it in a bag?

Tags: mac, power-management, magic-mouse

I guess the Apple Magic Mouse will turn itself off automatically to save power. However I am not sure whether it is woke up by movement, or by a human finger touch...

I carry my MacBook and Magic Mouse in my backpack. So should I turn it off to save power when I am on the street? Or it's clever enough to keep sleeping if no body touches it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may awaken from being moved with the bottom against something close enough to make it think it is being moved across a surface. So just to be safe, you might want to turn it off.